# Form Wizard: Redirecting back to a previous step when validation fails

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have implemented a wizard that consist of 4 forms.However i need to put a check on some variable say it its True go to next step else go to previous step.
I am inside process step:-

```
        def process_step(self, form):
            """
            you can save the form here,
            since it's guaranteed to be valid
            """
            guest_user = False
            if self.steps.current == "step1":
                step1_data = self.get_form_step_data(form)
            if self.steps.current == "step2":
                step2_data = self.get_form_step_data(form)
            if self.steps.current == "step3":
                step3_data = self.get_form_step_data(form)

            if self.steps.current == "step4":
                step4_data = self.get_form_step_data(form) 
                inv_data = check_inventory_for_cart_items(self.request)
            # At this point i want to redirect to step3    
            if not inv_data[0] == True:
                messages.error(self.request, "Some Items Out of stock. Please    check in order summary")
                    return  
            return super(SinglePageCheckoutWizard, self).process_step(form)
```

As you can i have put a return and hence it redirects to the same step template
but i want that it should redirect to previous step template.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you have a validation logic checking for "out-of-stock" status. Can you just check this on the step 3 instead?

Comment: I am doing this in step3 also but in the final step( that is payment) i need to make sure that the stock should be there. If it is not redirect the user to the previous step.

Comment: If the form is invalid in step 3, it should redirect back, can you show your form class for step3?